# Mirror a frame to a projector screen

Tags: frames

When using an external monitor/projector with Emacs, I use the Extend option (rather than Duplicate). Then I duplicate my work frame with `C-x 5 2`, that is `make-frame-command`, and I move the duplicate frame to the projector screen.

I further use activate `hl-line-mode` and

```
(setq cursor-in-non-selected-windows 'bar)
```

With this setting what I write on my laptop frame is mirrored on the projector frame, provided the it is  set to the same buffer.

My problem is that I can't mirror the selection highlight, which unfortunately is shown only in the frame where I am actually writing/selecting.

Any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've asked a very similar question yesterday and stumbled upon your post only afterwards …

Nevertheless, this answer might help (could not yet test it on an external monitor): https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/44905/20389

Answer (score 0):

You could use [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) and project the frame to the display you want. This way, you could also record a video (optionally with your voice) should it make sense.

Comment: Did you understand my problem? I am just giving a presentation. I need to mirror the content of a single Emacs buffer (not the whole Emacs windows) to an Emacs frame displayed on an external monitor.

Comment: Your question is phrased as if you wanted to mirror the whole frame.