# In-sync editing the same file in two frames

Tags: frames, text-editing, scrolling

For a lecture, I'll have a setup with two frames (one on my notebooks's screen, the other on the projector) showing the same file. When editing the file in the "master" frame I need the "slave" frame to be exactly in sync: both shall show the same position in the file, both shall scroll in sync. If I move the point in the "master" frame it shall move in the "slave" frame accordingly. In short, the "slave" has to be a clone of the "master".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both frames display the same buffer, then all that should be needed is to make sure the `window-point` and `window-start` of both frames are in sync.

Sync'ing is easier if it only goes one way, which should be an acceptable restriction in your case.  So you could try something like:

```
;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-
(defun my-clone-frame ()
  (let* ((src (selected-window))
         (src-point (copy-marker (window-point)))
         (src-start (copy-marker (window-start)))
         (clone (frame-root-window (make-frame))))
    (add-hook 'post-command-hook
              (lambda ()
                (unless (= src-point (window-point src))
                  (move-marker src-point (window-point src))
                  (set-window-point clone src-point))
                (unless (= src-start (window-start src))
                  (move-marker src-start (window-start src))
                  (set-window-start clone src-start))))))
```

Comment: Stefan, that's exactly what I was looking for. Btw, there is one closing paren missing at the very end.